# Problems with the CsrfToken when using the pager, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have in my blade template several hidden inputs with the csrf_token, which are sent in my form with the post method, however, when implementing the pager, I have the problem that this only uses the 'get' method and shows the token in The browser url, is there any way to send the inputs with the post method? I have tried enclosing the pagination class inside a form and then assigning the value of the href with jquery but it still does not work.

Comment: doesn't it work without the token? i don't think all get posts require the token by default

Comment: I think that for the search pages it's not good to use the post method, this problem arises with the pager, I do not really want to see the variables in the url but I think I will have to change everything to get, thanks for the suggestion, dude

Comment: Sorry, i missunderstood the question. If you want to use post instead of gets (wich makes sense) you have to append _token in thepost, if you're using any kind of plugin search for aditional request parameters and add _token, for example in data tables 
table.DataTable({
          ajax: {
              url: "{{route('getEvent')}}",
              method:"POST",
              data: function (data) {
                  data._token = "{{Session::token()}}";
                  delete data.columns;
              }
          }, //etc